# Youtube video in UIWebview not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, youtube

Using this code to play YouTube video in UIWebView

```
- (void)embedYouTube {

UIWebView *webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth); 
// iframe
videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
             <html>\
             <head>\
             <style type=\"text/css\">\
             iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
             body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
             </style>\
             </head>\
             <body>\
            <iframe width=\"560%%\" height=\"315px\" src=\"%@\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/j9CukQje2qw\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
             </body>\
             </html>", videoURL];

             [videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];

}
```

When i click on this LaunchVideo UIButton all it shows black screen on iOS device

```
-(void)LaunchVideo:(id)sender
{
self.videoURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/j9CukQje2qw";

WebViewController *webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

webViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
webViewController.videoURL = self.videoURL;

[self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

}
```

If anyone can point out what i m missing or doing wrong in this code. Why youtube video is not showing. Not using interface builder doing programmtically. Got this project code from web. Tried this project code on ios device it works fine for that project but when applied its code in my project then it is not working. Only difference that his projectcode from web uses interface builder and i am doing it programmtically.I dont get it.

Please help what is wrong with this code.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to load the youtube video into your app. First, put a UIWebView into your interface and size it to how big you want the video should show (there will be a button to make it full screen), then make an IBOutlet to it, so you can change its properties of hidden (to make it pop up and go away) Here is some code. In the code there is a method used called webviewshow, this calls a simple method that basically just says
    webview.hidden = NO;
    webviewbutton.hidden = NO;
Then there is a button that also pops up that makes the web view go away when tapped. Here is the code to load the youtube video into the web view

```
// Create your query ...
    NSString* searchQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/j9CukQje2qw];

    // Be careful to always URL encode things like spaces and other symbols that aren't URL friendly
    searchQuery = [searchQuery stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Now create the URL string ...
    NSString* urlString = searchQuery;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

    [webView loadRequest:request]; currentTimer= [NSTimer      scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(webviewshow) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];;
```

It waits 2 seconds (usual wait time for most connections) until the web view is shown, so the page is loaded and the user does not have to watch it load.

Then when you want to make the video go away, make a method to close the web view like so

```
- (void) makewebviewGoAway {webview.hidden = YES; webviewbutton.hidden = YES;}
```

Hopefully, that was helpful. IF you need further help or explanation, just comment off of this.

Comment: i m doing it programmatically and i want only this specific video to show i dont to show other videos of youtube or search query for videos. On the main window have uibutton when that button is pressed only then uiwebview displays youtube video to play

Comment: Thanks!!! I used this method over loading a whole HTML string and it works a lot better